# Updating content with $id doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm curious as to where my issue seems to be... I tried to use the `$id=$_GET['id']` command in order to collect the id and allow my sql row to be updated. Can anyone help me and see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Here's my database line up:

```
||idtest||testing
```

and the current update PHP:

```
<?php
  include("database_conn_test.php");
?>
<?php
  //select database table
          $sql = "SELECT testing FROM test";
          $queryresult = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

        //Request Values
          while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($queryresult)){
            $algemeneVoorwaarden = $res['testing'];
          }
          if(mysql_num_rows($queryresult) <= 0) {
            echo("");
          }

  if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE idtest=$id");
    $avID= mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $algemeneVoorwaarden = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['testing']);

    $updateAV = "UPDATE test SET testing=$algemeneVoorwaarden WHERE idtest=$avID";
    $result = mysql_query($updateAV);
  }
?>
```

And last but not least the HTML:

```
    <div class="tinyMCEWrapper">
  <script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">tinymce.init({selector: "textarea"});</script>
  <form method="post" action="test.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <textarea name="testing" id="content" class="algemeneAdmin" style="width:100%"><?php echo $algemeneVoorwaarden; ?>
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value = "<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I have figured out the area of incidence, but not how to fix it. I am doing something wrong with $id as it never receives a value...

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any exceptions? put it in a `try{}catch{}` block and echo the exception! However, you should instead be using PDO over the standard mysql libraries. [Why you should use PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: why are you using mysql_ ? `testing=$algemeneVoorwaarden` this might need quotes

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: how do you get `$_POST['testing']` from `<textarea name="content`?

Comment: You don't have a form element named `testing` - I.e.: `name="testing"` so this `$algemeneVoorwaarden` never gets updated and you probably need quotes around `SET testing=$algemeneVoorwaarden` - `SET testing='$algemeneVoorwaarden'`

Comment: @DanielA.White I know I'm going to update it after the code works. I've tried removing quotes but it doesn't change much. i've changed the name and it still doesn't put the id string in the url... i keep ending up with php?id= :/

Comment: You don't show a column named `id` in your table, so shouldn't `action="test.php?id=<?php echo $avID['id']; ?>"` be `action="test.php?id=<?php echo $avID['idtest']; ?>"`?

Comment: @Sean nope :/ it doesn't work

Comment: What's the url, on which you are testing this?

Comment: localhost for now @tastro. The code you see up there is almost all i'm working with...

Comment: @user3700201 what's the full url?

Comment: @tastro http://localhost/Testing%20Stuff/test.php?id=

Comment: @user3700201 you must include a number for the id. Like so: localhost/Testing%20Stuff/test.php?id=1 check which id do you have in your database.

Comment: @tastro that's my exact issue. I'm pressing the submit button after updating, and it is supposed to link to the url to confirm update. the ID links to the row i need to update, so i need that ID in the url to prove it worked.

Comment: @user3700201 But when you first access the url, you must specify an id.

Comment: Your $id is only initialized when its stored in $_GET... but its never initialized if its in the $_POST

  if($_POST){
    $algemeneVoorwaarden = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['testing']);

    $updateAV = "UPDATE test SET testing=$algemeneVoorwaarden WHERE idtest='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($updateAV);
  }

id is not initialized here... only in your if( isset($_GET['id']) ) block.

Comment: $avID  is an array, which element of the array you want to pass as idtest ?

Comment: In your case, you could replace `<form method="post" action="test.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">` with `<form method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

Your form is submitting using POST. This means that your `$_GET['id']` should be a `$_POST['id']`. Or you can change your form from `method="post"` to `method="get"` and it will use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: `action="test.php?id=<?php echo $avID['id']; ?>"`. The OP has redunant `id`, so they can use `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: i've tried both methods, but the only advance i'm getting is that upon submitting it shows what's in the content again. It's not updating though.... :/

Comment: From what I can see, your `$avID['id']` is only set when `$_GET['id']` is set. Show when you initially load the page do you have a get variable for id in the URL or no?

Comment: you're right, but now that i've changed it, it's still not making any sense :/

Comment: Now your `$id` is only set when your `$_POST['update']` is set. You need to have it set when your form is output so that the id is set inside the url like you are trying to do. If `$id` is not defined when your form is output, it does not know which id to update in your database.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to insert / update data in SQL database using PHP a while ago for my assignment:

Creating a connection to the database:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "pass", "database_name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Then in your code, when initializing variabels from POST, escape the strings:

```
$Name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["txtName"]);
$Street = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["txtStreet"]);
$City = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["txtCity"]);
```

Now, prepare a SQL code to insert your params:

```
$input = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO customer (MembershipID, Name, Street, City, PostCode, Email, Password, DateJoin, Salt) 
    VALUES ('". $MembershipID."','".$Name."','".$Street."','". $City."','". $PostCode."','". $Email."','". $Password."','". $DateJoined."','". $Salt."')");
```

and here is the update statement:

```
$updateAddress = $mysqli->query("UPDATE customer SET Street = '".$Street."', City = '".$City."', PostCode = '".$PostCode."' WHERE CustomerID = '".$_SESSION['loggedIn']."'");
```

Comment: OP should be instructed to add `session_start();` since your update statement contains a session variable `$_SESSION['loggedIn']`

Comment: i've got the connection to the database, i've posted the string, but i dont see how this is anything near what i'm looking for?

Comment: @user3700201 I see that you are using mysql_real_escape_string which is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. PHP manual strongly suggests to move over to MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension. And right here I provided you with example how to use MySQLi to connect to DB, insert and update.  Personally I think that the problem is with your UPDATE statement, PHP version or outdated extension such as mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end. Basically the problem was that there was no link to a page that directly linked to the ID (hence the URL), and I had problems with giving ID a value because i never received one. Anyway, the solution is the following on a separate page:

```
<?php
  include("database_conn_test.php");
?>
<?php
        //select database table
          $sql = "SELECT idtest, testing FROM test";
          $queryresult = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

        //Request Values
          while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($queryresult)){
            $algemeneVoorwaarden = $res['testing'];
            $algemeneID = $res['idtest'];

?>
<body> 
    <?php
          echo "<a href='testUpdate.php?id={$res['idtest']}'>Yo</a>";
         }

       if(mysql_num_rows($queryresult) <= 0) {
        echo("");
       }
    ?>
</body>
```

and then the other page that directly works with the ID. Sorry for all the trouble, but it was your contribution that led me to the answer! thank you so much everyone!